# Creating Non-Nullable Array Types With JSchemaGenerator

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net, jsonschema

I am using Newtonsoft.Json.schema v1.0.6 and I am trying to generate `JSchema` for custom type that has an array property that is similar to this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<MyChild> Children { get; set; }
}
public class MyChild {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The default `JSchemaGenerator` generates a `JSchema` similar to this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "MyChildren": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": [
                    "object",
                    "null"
                ],
                ...
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

I do not want to accept null items in the `MyChildren` array. I have tried adding the `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` attribute but it just makes the `MyChildren` property itself required and I cannot add the attribute to the `MyChild` class.

I figure I'm going to have to implement a custom `JSchemaGenerationProvider` but the `JSchema.Items` property is readonly.

How do I generate JSON schema for an object that has an array property that should not accept null values?

Answer (score 0):

`JSchema.Items` is readonly but the schema inside it can be modified. Just set its Type to `JSchemaType.String`.